# Angular 4 - Add a value to input

Tags: angular

I tried to put the value to `<input value="{{ val }}">` but I think its wrong because it returns empty data.

How can I set a default value to an input?

I already created API for update. I just really need to return the input data.

thanks

Comment: "I already created API for update" - so what do you do?  Do you look at the dom and values for the controls?  I think it would be better to use `ngModel` and do a proper binding.  You can create a separate object for your form and set the initial data whenever you want (just at the start?) like `this.formData = Object.assign({}, this.data);`, then use `formData` when you submit the form leaving your original `data` unchanged.

Answer (score 17):

You can use one-way input binding:

```
<input [value]="val">
```

or two-way input binding:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="val">
```

One-way will give you the value, and update it when the component updates it... but will not change the value with user input.

Two-way will change on user input as well as component changes.

Answer (score 3):

use this. It will show the data as well as do a two way binding. you can change its value from code to view and from view to code.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="val">
```